# linux: unable to kill non-zombie process

Tags: linux, memory, process

On ubuntu 14.04, I ran an grep command on all the logs, that started to take all memory (~48 Gb).

I tried to kill it, with kill -9, sudo kill -9, killall, pkill, whatever, but the process is still running and taking all memory.

```
%ps -f -p 28250
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
karl     28250     1  6 11:07 ?        00:02:46 grep --color=auto cron alternatives.log alternatives.log.1 ...

%sudo cat /proc/28250/syscall
running


%cat /proc/28250/status
Name:   grep
State:  R (running)
Tgid:   28250
Ngid:   0
Pid:    28250
PPid:   1
TracerPid:  0
Uid:    134000025   134000025   134000025   134000025
Gid:    134000017   134000017   134000017   134000017
FDSize: 256
Groups: 4 997 999 1004 134000000 134000002 134000017 134000028 
VmPeak: 71777208 kB
VmSize: 71777208 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:  42003200 kB
VmRSS:  41993348 kB
VmData: 71765652 kB
VmStk:       140 kB
VmExe:       180 kB
VmLib:      2168 kB
VmPTE:     91864 kB
VmSwap:  5013564 kB
Threads:    1
SigQ:   5/386055
SigPnd: 0000000000000100
ShdPnd: 0000000000044103
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000000000
SigCgt: 0000000000000000
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 0000001fffffffff
Seccomp:    0
Cpus_allowed:   ffffffff
Cpus_allowed_list:  0-31
Mems_allowed:   00000000,00000003
Mems_allowed_list:  0-1
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    28419
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 948133
```

I have the feeling that it is somewhat related with the fact that the lastlog is very huge because of very high user ids (because of freeIPA).

How to kill this process ?!?!?

Comment: Did you try to kill the father process PPID? It can be the shell itself. Of course check it before and  __do not kill init__ process else your system will collapse in a cycle. :-)

Comment: as you can see in my post, the PPID is 1.

Comment: Yes I realized (too late... I see your answer too). In similar cases it can be useful to suspend the process before with Ctrl-Z and then to kill it normally. The next sync can hang a little the system. The `kill -9`  can be unexpectedly slower and with an higher probability it will leave some waste... and maybe some zombie (`ps -aux | grep Z`).

Answer (score 0):

The process died eventually, at least 15 minutes after the kill -9.